# Why are all my component rerendering when I change an unrelated state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-hooks

I'm trying to change a state without having the entire app reload. For some reason that's not happening, and when I set the state of an object that isn't even passed down to a specific component, then that component updates for no reason.

So in the code below, I'm when I set the message, `MainContent` should not reload.

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState({});
setMessage('my message'); // This causes the entire app, including 'MyComponent' to reload

return (
    <div className='App'>
        <Header user={user} message={message} setMessage={setMessage} />

        <div id='main-site'>
            <Switch>
                // SHOULD NOT RELOAD UNLESS PASSED IN PROP CHANGED
                <Route path='/main' component={MainContent} />

            </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

**Header.jsx**

```
return (
    {message && (
        <div>
            <span>{message.text}</span>
            // This on click makes the entire app reload
            <button className='close' onClick={() => setMessage({})}>
                X
            </button>
        </div>
    )}
);
```

How can I make sure the only components that have the `message` prop get updated, and no other components rerender?

Comment: post the code for `setMessage`

Comment: @DanielLizik Edited, and added `const [message, setMessage] = useState({});` Is that what you meant?

Comment: isn't the correct hook usage `useState({ message: 'my message' })`?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable

Comment: @DanielLizik I don't think so. That is just initialization... I don't think it's mandatory to  assign a value on init...

Comment: "Any components below the root will also get unmounted and have their state destroyed" https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types

Comment: @DanielLizik Define below the root?

Comment: @DanielLizik I edited the question to add more context

Comment: make `MainContent` a `PureComponent` to not re-render unless consuming props change. I think your understanding is conflicting the re-render portion of the `MyComponent` (the one with useState). Once message gets updated that particular component gets re-rendered thus Switch > Route gets rendered again as expected

Comment: @DanielLizik `useState({ message: 'my message' })` is only if you want to pass initial value. Its not mandatory

Comment: Why don't you simply define that state in the Header component instead on that root component, because the way you wrote your code, it will always re-render, that's how react works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix your issue.

The First one involved moving your state down to the Child Component i.e Header since only Header uses `message` state. The Other thing to keep in mind is that you don't call state updater directly in render since it will keep calling the react state updater although it won't affect your app since react internally prevents re-render if the same state is supplied to state updater again.

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState({});
setMessage('my message');

return (
    {message && (
        <div>
            <span>{message.text}</span>
            // This on click makes the entire app reload
            <button className='close' onClick={() => setMessage({})}>
                X
            </button>
        </div>
    )}
);
```

The second way which is a more reliable way when you have to pass on message to more than one component is to make use of `React.memo` for the component

```
const MyComponent = () => (
   ...
);

export default React.memo(MyComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I tried the second solution, but still got the same effect. I can't do the first one, since I'll be using setMessage in multiple components

Comment: @SteveCahn No you don't need .redux for this

Comment: So then how can I go about it?

Comment: I tried the second solution but the bug is still there for me too

Answer (score 0):

You should define the hook into the component function. that binds the variable and it `setMessage` update function only to that component. 
In React the only way to update the dom is by recall all Pure Component or `render` function on `React.Component` and compare there return to previous return.

So to update the view after you change it by `SetMessage` react call again all render function to update the view.

```js
function MyComponet(){
  return (
    <div className='App'>
        <Header user={user} message={'my message'} />

        <div id='main-site'>
            <Switch>
                // SHOULD NOT RELOAD UNLESS PASSED IN PROP CHANGED
                <Route path='/main' component={MainContent} />

            </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}


//state that updating when props updating too
function usePropsState(initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  useEffect(() => setState(initialState), [initialState]);
  return [state, setState]
}

function Header({user, message:initMessage}){
  // now you can update the state internally or from outside
  const [message, setMessage] = usePropsState(initMessage);
  return (
    {message && (
        <div>
            <span>{message}</span>
            // This on click makes the entire app reload
            <button className='close' onClick={() => setMessage('')}>
                X
            </button>
        </div>
    )}
  );
}
```

If you like that custom hook thumb Up [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14830) issue

Comment: I update the code with a custom hook that helps you to update the `Header` state also from outside. so you can use different state management that more fit your need